# Google Calendar API: Get events as JSON

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been working through the documentation for hours, but I just can't figure it out. I need only access to my own calendar. So what steps do I have to take? How does the authentication work?

Thanks, 
Joe

Comment: For your information: I'm working with Java.

Comment: Is this a desktop application, web application, or mobile application? With each of them, OAuth 2.0 is handled differently. As to using the Calendar API, I recommend you roll your own solution rather than using the Google's Client Library for Java, simply because the documentation on the Client Library is almost non-existant.

Comment: it's a web application. How does the authentication work, when i use REST? I only want to access my own calendar (private calendar).

Comment: I think you could still use the Client Library for authentication unless the documentation on that is too poor. I built my own OAuth 2.0 solution but it's in VBA and it's also for a desktop/client application so I'm not sure I can help you a lot in that regard. I can give you the rough, concepts/overview but I think Google's documentation does that already.

Answer (score 0):

I used the this code to access the calendar list i.e., this returns the details of the calendars that I created. I hope it helps. I am using OAuth 2.0 draft 12 and Google Calendar API v3

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/authenticate.do" , method={ RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST })
    public void authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    List <String> scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
    scopes.add(scope);
    AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorize = new  GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(client_id, redirect_uri, scopes);
    authorize.setRedirectUri(redirect_uri);
    String authorize_url              = authorize.build();
    log.info(authorize_url);
    response.sendRedirect(authorize_url);
}
```

The function above takes care of the OAuth authentication and directs the user to the screen where they allow or deny. If they allow they are redirected to this function.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/importCalendar.do", method={ RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST })
public void importCalendarList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();

    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleTokenResponse res = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri).execute();
    String accessToken = res.getAccessToken();
    Calendar.Builder builder = new Calendar.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, null);  
    builder.setCalendarRequestInitializer(new CalendarRequestInitializer(accessToken));
    Calendar calendarService = builder.build();
    Calendar.CalendarList.List list = calendarService.calendarList().list();
    list.setOauthToken(accessToken);
    List <CalendarListEntry>list1=list.execute().getItems();
    String id = list1.get(0).getId();
    p.write(id);

    for(CalendarListEntry temp:list1) {
        p.println(temp.getSummary());
        temp.getId();
    } 
}
```

This function importCalendarList lists the names of all the calendars that the user has. The List of type CalendarListEntry is the Object representation of your calendars. So from getters you can get, for instance, the uniqueid of one of the calendars or the time zone of a calendar.

I wrote this program for knowing calendar api. Before I started writing I went to google api console to set these things up.

**client id, redirect uri, scope and client secret.** Set these up and use them in the program. This just shows the calendar list however you can also get, add, update and delete events from/to a calendar or do all these operations on a calendar itself. The comprehensive documentation for Google Calendar API is found here:

```
https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/index.html
```

and one last note. I did this from a web application. Hope this helps.